How to extract internal links using PyPDF
Got this far with PyPDF, trying to extract internal links:
    import pypdf

    internal_links = []
    with open(<pdf_path>, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        reader = pypdf.PdfReader(pdf_file)
        for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
            page = reader.pages[page_num]
            if "/Annots" in page:
                for annot in page["/Annots"]:
                    annot_obj = annot.get_object()
                    if annot_obj["/Subtype"] == "/Link":
                        if "/Dest" in annot_obj:
                            dest = annot_obj["/Dest"]
                            print(f"page: {page_num} dest: {dest}")

but can't figure out how to get the page number from dest. Looked in the pypdf codebase and also in the returned object, but still stuck. Any help appreciated :)

This seems to have been answered upstream in the meantime: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/discussions/2911

This is what i found out and worked.
for i in range(len(reader.pages)):
page = reader.pages[i]
# Extract text from page
pdf_text = page.extract_text()
# Print all URL
if "/Annots" in page:
    for annot in page["/Annots"]:
        annot_obj = annot.get_object()
        if annot_obj["/Subtype"] == "/Link":
            dest = annot_obj["/A"]["/URI"]
            print(f"page: {i} dest: {dest}")


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit your answer to include a brief description of the code? Answers with only code and no additional details are more likely to be marked as low-quality here.
